# How to fill layout corner with another layout color

Tags: android, user-interface, layout, imageview

[image]

In the given image where the search bar is located there are two layouts

1. Where the thumbnail is shown.
2. Where the list is shown.

But this not looks like they are divided because same color is filled  on the joining corners of both layouts.

I want this type of effect.

*See the marking in the image

Comment: give list divider color or image instead .

Comment: can you please explain!